# Bootstrap selectpicker option size inside a Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How do I adjust the width of a selectpicker's option within a Modal?
The width of the select is normally adjusted to the width of the modal, but when I open the selectpicker, the data in the option adjusts to the total width of the screen. Here's an example of how I'm using the modal:

**Code Snippet**

```js
$('#mymodal').modal('show')
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mymodal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius: 0">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h6 class="modal-title"> My Modal</h6>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <form role="form" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="action.do">
        <div class="modal-body" style="overflow: visible;">

          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-container="modal-body" data-live-search="true" required data-style="btn-light btn-outline-secondary btn-sm btn-custom">
              <option value=""><span>Select a value</span></option>
              <option value="1"><span>Value 1</span></option>
              <option value="2"><span>Value 2</span></option>
              <option value="3"><span>Value 3</span></option>
              <option value="4"><span>Value 4</span></option>
              <option value="5"><span>Value 5</span></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Exit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>




  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.6 -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

*click image to enlarge*

[image]
[image]

Comment: Removed, but the problem still persists.